# Is there any equivalent to the BizTalk ACK/NACK in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there any equivalent to the BizTalk ACK/NACK in Logic Apps?

e.g. usually we will have someone calling our logic app and getting back a "200 OK". But what happens when they timeout the request, but we've received it and started processing.

So we're left with them thinking the call failed, and we think it succeeded

Comment: by "NACK" you mean negative functional/technical ack from the EDI operations?

Comment: Not specifically EDI, but the generic positive and negative acknowledgements functionality in BizTalk messaging engine ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559421.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You return a 202, HttpStatusCode.Accepted to caller.